# DBConcurrencyException in SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, database

He everybody,

Recently I've started a project that needs a lot of data. So much in fact it cannot be stored in the runtime memory. 
I've been looking for solutions to this problem and have chosen for the use of a SQL databases.
I found a tutorial explaining how they work and recreated it myself. It makes sure your physical database and virtual dataset stay in sync by using a dataAdapter to update the database;

(FYI the tutorial can be found here: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p1.html);

However when expanding a tutorial i came across an error i cant explain namely: DBConcurrencyException.

When i run the program all functionality works, i can add a row and delete a row. But when i try to do both in the same execution (order = add then delete) the error comes up.
It describes that zero of the one expected records were affected by the DeleteCommand.

The following code snippits is what i used:

Initialization:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection();
            ds1 = new DataSet();

            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\<Private>\\MyWorkers.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";

            con.Open();

            string sql = "SELECT * From tblWorkers";
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);

            da.Fill(ds1, "Workers");
            NavigateRecords();

            MaxRows = ds1.Tables["Workers"].Rows.Count;
            updateIndicator();

            con.Close();
            //con.Dispose();
        }
```

(Note: I commented out the directory for privacy reasons);

The addition of a row is done as followed:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

            DataRow dRow = ds1.Tables["Workers"].NewRow();

            dRow[1] = textBox1.Text;
            dRow[2] = textBox2.Text;
            dRow[3] = textBox3.Text;

            ds1.Tables["Workers"].Rows.Add(dRow);

            MaxRows = MaxRows + 1;
            inc = MaxRows - 1;

            da.Update(ds1, "Workers");

            MessageBox.Show("Entry Added");
        }
```

When deleting a row this code is executed:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

            ds1.Tables["Workers"].Rows[inc].Delete();
            MaxRows--;
            inc = 0;
            NavigateRecords();

            da.Update(ds1, "Workers");

            MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted");
        }
```

The NavigateRecord() method and setIndicator() method are not relevant in this question since they are GUI elements.

Thanks in advance everybody!

Comment: How are you trying to do them both in the same time?My guess is that your add function fails and then the delete throws this error.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good idea. Why are you deleting a record based off of a static variable indicating the record index in the datatable (`inc`)? What happens if someone adds two records in a row before pressing the delete button?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this <strike>question</strike> statement while looking for a way to prevent SQL Server from locking an entire record (I want it to lock by field / column value instead) and noticed that no answer had been given, so here ya go if anyone else runs into this problem:

OP didn't actually ask a question, only stated what the problem was; so here's the answer to the question that wasn't asked "How do I prevent Database Concurrency Violations?":

Database Concurrency Violations (in this case) are preventable by making a decision as to which data gets to go in to the database.  Most people elect to take the approach that 'last in wins'.  So, in your handling of operations using the TableAdapter, put the Update in a Try/Catch and during Catch for DBConcurrencyException just make sure you do a quick Fill, then change whatever you were supposed to be changing, and then do the Update.  Works every time.